# memcpy behaving in an unexpected way

Tags: c++, c, pointers, out-of-memory, memcpy

Given below is my sample code :

```
int function1(unsigned char *out, int length){
unsigned long crypto_out_len = 16;
unsigned char crypto_out[16] = {0};
.......
//produces 16 bytes output & stores in crypto_out
crypto_function(crypto_out, crypto_out_len); 
//lets say crypto_output contents after are : "abcdefghijklmnop"
.......
memcpy(out, crypto_out,length);
return 0;
}

function2(){
unsigned char out[10] = {0};
function1(out, 10);
std::pair<unsigned char *,int> map_entry;
map_entry.first = out;
map_entry.second = 10;
}
```

Now, map_entry.first should contain : "abcdefghij", right?

But it contains "abcdefghij#$%f1^", some garbage associated with it. How should I avoid such unexpected behaviour so that `map_entry.first` should contain exactly "abcdefghij".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't pasted the whole code, I can't be 100% sure but I think I know what's wrong. `memcpy()` is behaving correctly here, and everything is 100% defined behavior.

In this case, `out` is a 10-character string *without* a null terminator. You assign it to `unsigned char*` that contains no length information, and I suspect you simply don't use the number ten when you are referring to `map_entry.first`.

If you print it as `unsigned char*` or construct a `std::string` with it, C++ expects it to be a null-terminated string. Therefore, it reads it up until the first null character. Now, since `out` didn't have one it just runs over and starts reading characters on the stack after `out` which happen to be what you see as garbage.

What you need to do, is make sure that *either* the string is null-terminated or make sure that you always refer to it specifying the correct length. For the former, you'd want to make `out` 11-byte long, and leave the last byte as `0`:

```
function2(){
    unsigned char out[11] = {0};
    function1(out, 10);
    std::pair<unsigned char *,int> map_entry;
    map_entry.first = out;
    map_entry.second = 10;
}
```

Please also note that C++ will actually stop at the first null character it encounters. If your `crypto_function()` may output zero bytes in the middle of the string, you should be aware that the string will be truncated at the point.

For the latter, you'd have to use functions that actually allow you to specify the string length, and always pass the length of `10` to those. If you always work with it like this, you don't have to worry about zero bytes from `crypto_function()`.

Comment: but just to make sure, memcpy copies null characters also from src to dest, right?

Comment: Yes. `memcpy()` copies specified number of bytes and doesn't care about null characters at all. `strcpy()` and `strncpy()` stop at null character.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing `char[]` with strings. `out` does contain your expected data, but its not 0 terminated, so if you try to display it as a string it may look like it contains extra data. If the data is actually strings, you need to correctly 0 terminate them.